# jquery can't append <img> to particular table column / <td> with particular nth-child() or eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very strange situation - I can add image to all `<td>` tags in `<tr>`, but can't add to specific `<td>` only, it adds image to wrong place, to last item in column only

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://kaymo75663.i.lithium.com/html/rank_icons/Icon-16x16TeamViewer-2016.png';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tbody.gridcontents_ticketmanagegrid_parent tr').each(function() {
        //console.log($(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').html()); --> prints right html, where I need to add image
        // console.log($(this).find('td:eq(3)').html()); --> also prints right html, where I need to add image
        // $(this).find("td").append(img); --> work fine, add image to every cell
        $(this).find('td:eq(3)').append(img); // --> doesn't work for some unknown reason!
        $(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').append(img); // --> doesn't work for some unknown reason!
    });
});
```

I tried with jquery 1.11.0 and 2.1.0, same result :(

Please help me to troubleshoot the problem

Here is an example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/serikov/brxkq7o6/,  here I want to add team viewer icon to all items in Lastname column

Comment: There's only one image at all. You need one image per table cell.

Comment: I don't think that you can add the same element to the DOM more than once. Use the jQuery `.clone()` method to create copies of the image you want to add.

Comment: @Quagaar, you are right, many thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Simple solution

Please edit the `$('table tr')` to `$('table')` , then find each `tr` with `td`. See fiddle below, 
https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/brxkq7o6/4/

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, solution is simple - use `.append($.clone(img))` instead of `.append(img)`. Seems like we can't add the same element to the DOM more than once

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://kaymo75663.i.lithium.com/html/rank_icons/Icon-16x16TeamViewer-2016.png';
    $('table').each( function(){
        $(this).find('tr td:nth-child(3)').append(img);
    });
 });
```